# Regular Expression Syntax Error

Tags: javascript, regex

I am creating a regex dynamically.

```js
    var link = "www.google.com";
    var reg = '^'+link+'{1}|(?<=\s)'+link+'{1}(?=\s)|'+link+'{1}$';
    console.log(reg);
    var result = new RegExp(reg, 'g');
```

I am getting this error

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /^www.google.com{1}|(?<=s)www.google.com{1}(?=s)|www.google.com{1}$/: Invalid group
```

Here is the generated regex:

`^www.google.com{1}|(?<=s)www.google.com{1}(?=s)|www.google.com{1}$`

Comment: Did you use some non-JS syntax? For example I do not recognise `?<=`

Comment: Why the close vote???

Comment: It ensures that the given pattern will match, ending at the current position in the expression. Does not consume any characters.
Ex :   /(?<=foo)bar/ Match : foobar

Comment: It gives me a red light here: http://regexpal.com/

Comment: JavaScript does not support lookbehind. There are various workarounds; I can not tell you which to use from the information you provide
.

Comment: As I surmised. And shown in the regular expression tester. - there are [several SO answers involving lookbehind](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+lookbehind)

Comment: By the way: I do not think this regex does what you expect. . stands for every character (but newlines); {1} is useless;  ....com{1} means ....co(m{1});  If the lookbehind would work wwwwgoogle3com would be valid.

Comment: is there any alternative for look-behind in javascript ??

Comment: Please look at the link I posted earlier

Comment: i apreciate your help.. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

JavaScript regex engine did not support look-behinds *at all* before ECMAScript 2018 was released.

Now, if you use this in Chrome, it will not throw any error now:

```js
var link = "www.google.com";
var reg = '^'+link+'{1}|(?<=\s)'+link+'{1}(?=\s)|'+link+'{1}$';
console.log(reg);
var result = new RegExp(reg, 'g');
```

Another thing: you must double escape `\` inside RegExp constructor.

What you are trying to acheive is to make the URL match at word boundaries.

Try using

```
RegExp.escape= function(s) {
    return s.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&');
};

var reg = '\\b'+RegExp.escape(link)+'\\b';
```

Code:

```js
RegExp.escape= function(s) {
        return s.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&');
    };

var link = "www.google.com"
var reg = '\\b'+RegExp.escape(link)+'\\b';
alert(new RegExp(reg, "g"));
```

**Note** I am adding the `RegExp.Escape` in order to escape special characters in the arguments passed to the `RegExp` constructor (e.g. `.` must be `\\.`).

Comment: is there any alternative for look-behind in javascript ??

Comment: i apreciate your help.. Thank you.

Comment: [There are alternatives](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/mimic-lookbehind-javascript), but there is none in case you have undefined number of characters before and after the string you want to match.

Comment: Do you need more assistance with this, or is everything working as expected?

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript does not support lookbehind groups.

On top of that, your regular expression is being built up from strings. You have to make sure that your regular expression metacharacters "survive" the process of string constant parsing, and in particular your `\s` needs to be expressed as `\\s`.

Note also that the `.` characters in the URL portion of your pattern will be interpreted as the regex "wildcard" symbol if you don't precede them with `\\` as well.

<strike>Finally, it's not clear what you expect those `{1}` things to do; in JavaScript that will match the sequence of characters `{1}`.</strike>

Comment: `{1}` is a quantifier (albeit a useless one). `/^m{1}$/.test('m')` returns `true` (in Firefox at least).

Comment: @FelixKling oh durr. Not enough coffee yet :)

Comment: No worries :) It wouldn't have been that surprising to me if `{1}` was treated differently ;)

Comment: i apreciate your help.. Thank you.